# CSS rotate 2 images in opposite directions over avatar image

Tags: css, image, rotation

When hover the central image this should animate 2 circles parts in opposite directions at the same time. Until now i only manage to animate them separetly by hovering the 2 objects separetly.

Here is the goal:
[image]

Here is my CodePen:
http://codepen.io/beng_beng/pen/Azstr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `:hover` on the `a#rotator` instead:

```
a#rotator:hover > img{ 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); 
 -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg); 
}

a#rotator:hover span img{ 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
 -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```

### [Demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rcjlp)